# Inserting rows at the top with animation inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row, insertion

I have standard UITableView with custom UITableViewCell. What I want to achieve is that:

- Each row should fade in one at a time while appearing on the TableView.
- **However, with the caveat that each new row should always be inserted at the top** thereby pushing previously existing rows down by 1 cell - to get get a "pushing onto stack" animation.

Here's what I have until now, which does the individual insertions with vanilla fade in but at bottom:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  cell.alpha = 0
  let delayBetweenRowInserts = 0.5 + Double(indexPath.row) * 1.0; //calculate delay
  UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: delayBetweenRowInserts, options: .TransitionCurlUp, animations: {
     cell.alpha = 1.0
     }, completion: nil
  )
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if let cell = leaderboardTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CUSTOM_CELL) as? CustomTableViewCell {
      let playerName = Array(Games.leaderboard[indexPath.row].keys)[0]
      let playerScore = Array(Games.leaderboard[indexPath.row].values)[0]
      cell.configureCell(playerName, score: "\(playerScore)")
      return cell
   } else {
       return UITableViewCell()
   }   
}
```

Motivation: **I essentially have to exhaust all the data in my dataSource array in one go**, i.e. Games.leaderboard without relying on the user to scroll down in case his screen size is too small to fit everything. This forms a very critical part of my app's UX.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you

P.S As an alternative I tried using beginUpdates() with .Top:
I have tried using beginUpdates(). Looks to me like it doesn't alter the index of the animating row. I am calling `startInsertingRows()` after dataSource is ready:

```
func startInsertingRows() {
    var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()
    for index in 0...Games.leaderboard.count-1 {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: Games.leaderboard.count-1-index, inSection: 0))
    }
    leaderboardTableView.beginUpdates()
    leaderboardTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths((indexPaths), withRowAnimation: .Top)
    leaderboardTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Dont really understand your req, but if you want the pushing animation, you can use `let sections = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections))` then `self.tableView.reloadSections(sections, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)` instead of `tableView.reloadData`

Comment: @Tj3n Per my current code: 

-row insert animation happens in a way that the first row to appear on the table stays on top and subsequent rows get added to the bottom. -However, I want that latest row, i.e. current indexPath.row to always be inserted at the top and older rows get pushed down - kind of like a facebook/twitter feed update, but with individual animation

Comment: Its kinda easy isnt it, have you tried `beginUpdate`, add object to your dataSource, then call `insertRowAtIndexPath`, and `endUpdate`

Comment: I think you can get rid of `willDisplayCell ` and instead, use 2 array, one hold your full data, and one use for updating your table, make a `NSTimer` for delay and insert the last cell individually and remove that timer once all data got populated

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by manipulating the value returned by `numberOfRowsInSection` and an `NSTimer` that manipulates this value. For simplicity, my version uses a fixed time interval, but you could use a non-repeating timer and schedule again in `tableTick`.  Also, I kick off the animation in `viewDidAppear`, but that may not be suitable in your case if the data is not already loaded, but you can adapt as required.

```
var tableTimer: NSTimer?
var cellPointer = 0

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    cellPointer = Games.leaderboard.count
    self.tableTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.tableTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func tableTick() {
    if cellPointer > 0 {
        cellPointer -= 1
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else {
        self.tableTimer!.invalidate()
        self.tableTimer = nil
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let timer = self.tableTimer {
        timer.invalidate()
        self.tableTimer = nil
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Games.leaderboard.count-self.cellPointer
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = leaderboardTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CUSTOM_CELL) as? CustomTableViewCell {
        let index = cellPointer + indexPath.row
        let playerName = Array(Games.leaderboard[index].keys)[0]
        let playerScore = Array(Games.leaderboard[index].values)[0]
        cell.configureCell(playerName, score: "\(playerScore)")
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```